# _Click Activity guide/documentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation

Is there a guide or **step-by-step instruction** on how to set this **_Click** activity on **SFMC**?

Comment: You don't set it.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs how will this be added on journey?

Comment: in a journey, the click pulls up data based on the email just before the engagement split. As Nerti_h pointed out, the _Click is just a view that records all clicks made in emails.

Answer (score 2):

The _Click System Data View is a record of all clicks made by Subscriber, no need to set anything.